# Does the search engine read the HTML before JS is loaded or after?

Tags: javascript, html, seo

Let's say that I have a nice and clean HTML document, but with JS I have to add several wrappers and what not to make some fancy things like promo sliders and etc.

My question is, does google see the clean, original HTML document, or does it see the document AFTER javascript is loaded and the html is messy.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that search engines run JavaScript on each page at all?

Comment: I don't think anything, I'm just asking what it does.

Answer (score 2):

> Googlebot keeps getting smarter. Now has the ability to execute AJAX/JS to index some dynamic comments http://goo.gl/F9et1

*Matt Cutts, Google, Nov 01 2011, https://twitter.com/mattcutts/status/131425949597179904*